# Foreign reference in data mapper

Tags: ruby-datamapper

Say I have two data mapper classes like this:

```
class Family
   include DataMapper::Resource

   property :id,   Serial
   property :nice, Boolean
end

Class Person
   include DataMapper::Resource

   property :id, Serial

   belongs_to :family
end
```

If I want to get all the people belonging to a certain family `family`, I can use this:

```
people=Person.all(:family=>family)
```

But what if I want to get all people who belong to a family which have the `nice` attribute? In SQL I could do

```
SELECT * FROM persons, families WHERE persons.family_id=families.id AND families.nice
```

Is there a nice way to do this in data mapper without dropping to the underlying dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that a `Family` has several `Person`s. See the [documentation on `has n` and `belongs_to`](http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html).

```rb
class Family
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,   Serial
  property :nice, Boolean

  # add this:
  has n, :people
end
```

Then you can use this:

```rb
Family.all(:nice => true).people
```

The SQL generated is actually a subquery rather than a join:

```sql
 SELECT "id", "family_id" FROM "people" WHERE "family_id" IN (SELECT "id" FROM "families" WHERE "nice" = 't') ORDER BY "id"
```